# Build a simple array in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have never had to build an array in android like the following, and I think there are errors in my syntax.

I am trying to accomplish somethign like:

```
String RoomName[] = {"145"="PentHouse","125"="BoardRoom","45"="ShopRoom","8"="MainOffice"};
```

so If I reference something like:

```
String CurrentRoom = RoomName["8"];
```

I want CurrentRoom to be equal to MainOffice.

I know I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't want an array, you want a map:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("145", "PentHouse");
map.put("125", "BoardRoom");
map.put("145", "PentHouse");
// etc

String room = map.get("8");
// room will be null if "8" isn't a key in the map.
```

Comment: Thanks your example is exactly what I am trying to accomplish +1 and will check shortly.

Answer (score 3):

Java don't have associative arays, use HashMap instead

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html

```
HashMap<String, String> HM = new HashMap<String, String>();
HM.put("key1","value1");
HM.put("key2","value2");
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you want a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), not an array.

You can look at the examples in [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't store arrays like that, what you're looking for is a `Map<String, String>` to hold key/value pairs.

For instance:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
myMap.put("145", "Penthouse");
...
String penthouse = myMap.get("145");  // will return "Penthouse"
```